# 2 questions about page layout - multi "row" and "central" header

Tags: header-footer, multicol

I have tried to google a lot, but I didn't get a clue. Maybe my request is a little special. :)
What I want to is to set the page with 2 part top and bottom, it's just like "multicolumn", but transpose. 
Another request is to set header(section name and page) to the central of page, where is the blank by two "rows" texts.
I am not sure if I have put this clearly. I have draw a draft and attached to make a better presentation. [image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to understand your situation and suggest the best approach when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. For example, it is definitely going to matter which document class etc. you are using and which packages you are trying to use to configure the page layout you want.

Comment: It would also help to know why you want to do this because the sort of project affects the practicality of various possibilities. There is no simple way to do what you want because sticking stuff in the middle of the text flow is necessarily going to mess things up. For some purposes, those things may not matter much. For others, they will. Could you not just put two pages on each sheet? So that you'd have a page of text, then whatever in the middle, then another page of text? Rather than putting something in the middle of each page?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`flowfram` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using the `flowfram` package.  One simple version is as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{flowfram}

\newflowframe{\textwidth}{0.4\textheight}{0pt}{0.6\textheight}[main]
\newdynamicframe*{\textwidth}{\baselineskip}{0pt}{0.5\textheight}[headers]
\newflowframe{\textwidth}{0.4\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext} %For dummy text
\begin{document}

\begin{dynamiccontents*}{headers}
  Section \thesection\quad \leftmark \hfill \thesubsection\quad\rightmark \hfill \thepage 
\end{dynamiccontents*}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

The preamble sets up two frames for the main text via `\newflowframe`.  The arguments specify the width of the area, its height and its position relative to the bottom left corner of the main text block.  The header information is put in a dynamic frame and the contents set with the `dynamiccontents` environment.  The `*` in the dynamic frame definition means that it gets a box drawn around it.  For the header information I have set up the marks so that they record the section and subsection names.

Comment: This is really a very cool package which can almost meet my requirement. Thanks a lot for your help!